Ansible module in a runtime EE
I try to install a module in ansible AWX EE pod. That module is needed for the playbook to execute the "desired code".
After the playbook execution the pod/ee is deleted.
I have both installation module yaml and my desired code. When I run them both in the same playbook I got an error that the module is missing even though I have the task to install it.
When I run the playbook just with the module installation it gets installed.
Problems:
How can I run the installation of the module and the next tasks in the same playbook?

it's irrelevant of how i structure the playbook: roles, task, split the playbook in 2 etc. AWX will always say that I have to install the module and I don't want a custom EE for this

It's impossible by design. I believe the answers to Ansible couldn't resolve module/action 'community.general.xml' and How do I install and use an Ansible collection within an AWX playbook at run time? might be helpful to clarify the reason.

Plus, container environments are meant to be immutable, and runtime modifications could be even impossible due to security reasons.

yes, I think brinks clarification over my question.
Thank you for the comment @AlexanderPletnev
I already create a new EE with the custom module which it's ok.
